# ssh-keygen: signing syntax - help needed with options

Tags: ssh, debian, ssh-keys

I am trying to sign some SSH keys with restricted options.

My initial attempt was as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -s /path/to/ca-ssh.pem -D opensc-pkcs11.so -n barfoo -O no-agent-forwarding -O no-port-forwarding -O no-x11-forwarding -O no-user-rc -O no-pty -I foo -z 12345 /path/to/pub
```

However this yields a result with no options present:

```
    $ ssh-keygen -L -f
    Type: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com user certificate                                                                                                                           
    Public key: ED25519-CERT SHA256:secretsquirrel                                                                                                      
    Signing CA: RSA SHA256: secretsquirrel                                                                                                                
    Key ID: "foo"                                                                                                                                        
    Serial: 12345                                                                                                                                                       
    Valid: forever                                                                                                                                                                    
    Principals:                                                                                                                                                                       
            barfoo                                                                                                                                                                       
    Critical Options: (none)                                                                                                                                                          
    Extensions: (none)
```

First I thought I would add `-O clear` before the other options. But that yielded the same result `(none)`.

So I then thought I would try `-O critical:no-agent-forwarding` style syntax, but this yeilds:

```
Critical Options:
        no-agent-forwarding UNKNOWN OPTION (len 0)
```

Finally I tried `-O critical:no-agent-forwarding=true`, but this yields the same `UNKNOWN OPTION` as above.

Not that it should matter, but the versions I'm using are :

- Debian 10 (buster)
- OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d
  10 Sep 2019

Comment: Can't you just add these to the start of the public key? As in `no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa ABCD...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually already achieved what you want to do: disable all permissions, which means your list of "extensions" is empty. See what happens if you do not use `-O` at all, i.e `ssh-keygen -s /path/to/ca-ssh.pem -D opensc-pkcs11.so -n barfoo -I foo -z 12345 /path/to/pub` -What extensions are enabled then?

-All the options you are using are "no-xxxx" which means you are *disabling* extensions and thus emptying the list of extensions. -Instead of disabling/removing them one by one, you could use `-O clear` only.
From the [man-page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#CERTIFICATES):

> clear ---- Clear all enabled permissions. This is useful for clearing the default set of permissions so permissions may be added individually.